# Group columns in python and then generate a csv

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I read a pdf that contains data from a spreadsheet, but the columns are repeated and I want to group them together to become a column in each topic.

I want to leave them in order by date and finish transforming into a csv,
but I don't know how to do that.

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd

lista_tabelas = tabula.read_pdf(r"C:\Carlo\Projetos\projeto1\20220811.pdf", pages="all", encoding='utf-8', stream=True)

#print(type(lista_tabelas))


print(lista_tabelas[0])
```

Result

```
Competência Remuneração  Indicadores Competência.1  ... Indicadores.1  Competência.2 Remuneração.2 Indicadores.2
0     05/2000      132,00          NaN       06/2000  ...           NaN        07/2000        230,00           NaN
1     08/2000      230,00          NaN       09/2000  ...           NaN        10/2000        228,95           NaN
2     11/2000      221,12          NaN       12/2000  ...           NaN            NaN           NaN           NaN
3     03/2001       14,84          NaN       04/2001  ...           NaN            NaN           NaN           NaN

[4 rows x 9 columns]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Competência Remuneração Indicadores
05/2000     230          NaN
06/2000     132          NaN
07/2000     221,12       NaN
08/2000     221,12       NaN
09/2000     216,68       NaN
10/2000     222,928      NaN
11/2000     229,176      NaN
12/2000     235,424      NaN
```

Comment: Don't post images of code.  Paste the code into your question, highlight the pasted code, and press the brackets `{}` in the toolbar to format it as code.  You can also format your dataframe as code.

Comment: Same goes for your data. Both sample data and desired results, pasted as text or formatted as a table using markdown. Please include both sample data and desired results. Furthermore, we don't know what a "Topic" is or what you mean by "Group them together". How does one group together columns? Desired results would help explain.

Comment: So you are getting this pattern: Competencia, remunerazao, indicadores .....
Are you getting Nan for all the columns with indicadores?

Comment: @JNevill I think now I understand

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos No, some have information.

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long` might be helpful https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Comment: You can find a way here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395022/create-a-new-dataframe-based-on-columns-name/73395157#73395157